# WindowsPhone Silverlight App 8.0 is stopping in breaking points created by the system but no error is showed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, breakpoints, windows-phone-silverlight

I cretead a Windows Phone runtime app but because there was an implementation I could get only with Silverlight I created a Silverlight app and paste all the classes and pages into it.

First I get many errors but I fixed all of them changing the code to the equivalent in Silverlight.

Now I am trying to run the app and It stops in breaking points created by the system but I have no idea of where is the problem. I would be grateful if someone could point me a light.

This is what happens:

step 1

[image]

step 2

[image]

step 3

[image]

step 4

[image]

step 5

[image]

step 6

[image]

step 7

[image]

step 8

Then it goes back.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Open the exceptions panel in Visual Studio (Ctrl + alt + E), and check that "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is fully checked. You may also have to uncheck "Enable Just my code" in the debugging options (Tools -> Options -> Debugging). Then, when you launch the app, the debugger should break right when the exception occurs, and you can then check the callstack to understand where it happens. Note that the debugger may also break on "normal" exceptions (that are catched by the code), so you have to sort out the noise

Comment: I don´t know the reason for the down vote. Why don´t they comment here? Bad people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please debug your code. my be somewhere Null data passing in it..
that's y it does not given you any error.. and direct give exception..

Comment: So yes, that was it. But I don´t know how I fount out. I just found.